# How to Change the Domain URL of website and sub-links of the website using single code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a string to the main domain, and also to the sub links of the website.

I tried the below code but main domain is not getting changed, I want to change main domain first and after reload of the website all the sub links should change.

```
 if (typeof this.href != "undefined") {
        web = this.href.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
    else{
        web = document.location.toString().toLowerCase();
    }

    function urlAddress() {
        confirm('Would you like to clear the cache.......... of '+ web + '- Ninja :)');
        //window.location.replace(web + "/?NoCDN=123");
        var stateObj = web;
        if (window.history.state) {
          history.pushState(stateObj, "page 1", "/?NoCDN=123");
        }

      }

     /*Second Function
     This code is changing all URL of the website...*/

    function linkAddress() {
        $('a[href]').each(function(){
            var link = this.href;
            $(this).attr('href',link + '?NoCDN=123');
        });

        $('script[src]').each(function(){
          var link = this.href;
          $(this).attr('src',link + '?NoCDN=123');
        });

        $('link[href]').each(function(){
          var link = this.href;
          $(this).attr('href',link + '?NoCDN=123');
        });

        $('img[src]').each(function(){
          var link = this.src;
          $(this).attr('src',link + '?NoCDN=123');
        });
    }

   //I am calling both functions here ...

    $( document ).ready(function() {
    urlAddress();
    setTimeout(function(){
    alert("It's Almost clear. Just click Ok for more result.");
    linkAddress();

    }, 3000);

    });
```